# PHP/HTML : Getting user input for google calendar embed code

Tags: php, html, wordpress, iframe, plugins

I have a custom WP plugin, where there is an option to input the google calendar embedded  code under a user's account.  The problem I am having is, whether a textarea OR text type input, the value is removed  and I can not gain access to the code.  They all come up blank/empty.  Ideally I would like to treat this embed code as a string, not code.

I see the embed code being generated on the google calendar website, so I know it can be done.  How can I have the user cut and paste this code from google to the their account on this website?

What I have tried is very simple code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['SEND_INFO']))
  {
  $googleembed1 = sanitize_text_field($_POST["textareatype"]);    <===== does not work
  $googleembed2 = sanitize_text_field($_POST["texttype"]);        <===== does not work

  // PRINT OUT <IFRAME> EMBED CODE AS TEXT
   DebugLog("TextArea with Sanitize: " . (string)$googleembed1);
   DebugLog("Text Input with Sanitize: " . (string)$googleembed2);
  }
?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post" >
<textarea id="textareatype" name="textareatype"></textarea>
<input type="text" id="texttype" name="texttype">
<input type="submit" id="SEND_INFO name="SEND_INFO" value="SAVE CHANGES"/>
</form>
```

```
LOGGED RESULTS:
TextArea with Sanitize:
Text Input with Sanitize:
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you trying to do this through an iframe? where can you run this code? which way? In WordPress Admin some specific places you can create a different way or register a form ...

Comment: I am trying to do this through a form, where one of the fields (textarea) shall contain a <iframe> string.  It then saves it to a custom database.   If I put the <iframe> string into the database directly, it reads it properly and display it.  But since this is a input process for customers, I want it the other way around.  Each person can then cut and past a google public calendar embed code into the field for use.

Comment: Solved the problem in terms of the string,

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, but it does require some physical comparison, since you can not use the sanitize_text_field() call, normally used in the WP environment to protect data input.
Here is the solution:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['SEND_INFO']))
  {
  $googlecalendar = stripslashes($_POST["textareatype"]);    
     $googlecalendar = str_replace("<iframe src=","",$googlecalendar);
     $googlecalendar = str_replace("<iframesrc=","",$googlecalendar);
     $googlecalendar = str_replace("></iframe>","",$googlecalendar);
     $googlecalendar = filter_var($googlecalendar, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

     if( strstr($googlecalendar, "<script")) 
        $googlecalendar = "";


     if( strstr($googlecalendar, "</script>"))
        $googlecalendar = "";


     if( strstr($googlecalendar, "<?php")) 
        $googlecalendar = "";

     if( strstr($googlecalendar, "?>")) 
        $googlecalendar = "";

     if( strstr($googlecalendar, ")") ||  strstr($googlecalendar, "(")) 
        $googlecalendar = "";        

     if( strstr($googlecalendar, "SELECT") ||  strstr($googlecalendar, "select")) 
        $googlecalendar = "";   

     if(strlen($googlecalendar)>0)
       {
       if( !strstr($googlecalendar, "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed") ) 
        $googlecalendar = "";   
       }
  }
?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post" >
<textarea id="textareatype" name="textareatype"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="SEND_INFO name="SEND_INFO" value="SAVE CHANGES"/>
</form>
```

Suggestion for other things to independently check for is welcome.